# SQL Select rows where two columns are equal, but a third is different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, email, sql-server-2012, filtering

I'm pretty sure the problem I'm having is that I'm not quite sure how to ask my question clearly, so I can't search for the answer.  But here goes...

I've got data that looks like this (simplified here):

```
ID    |  MailboxID   | Connection |  EmailID
0001  |  M0001       | 1          |  9999
0002  |  M0001       | 2          |  9999
0003  |  M0002       | 1          |  9998
0004  |  M0002       | 2          |  9998
0005  |  M0002       | 2          |  9997
0006  |  M0003       | 1          |  9996
```

ID is a primary key, so it is unique in the table.  MailboxID indicates the mailbox the message is stored in.  Connection tells me which internal connection (basically a task ID) the mailbox exists in, and the EmailID is a unique identifier for an email.

I need to return all ID's where MailboxID and EmailID are equal but the Connection is different.  In the example above, I'd want to return these rows: ID 0001-0002, 0003-0004.  Anyone able to lend a hand?

Comment: Based on your question I don't understand why you want 0003-0004 returning.

Comment: Oops...copy/paste error.  Connection for 0004 should be 2.  I'll edit.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming there are no nulls, your numbers are integers and your strings have no spaces needing to be trimmed:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mailbox](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MailboxId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Connection] [int] NULL,
    [EmailId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Mailbox] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0001, 'M0001', 1, 9999);
INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0002, 'M0001', 2, 9999);
INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0003, 'M0002', 1, 9998);
INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0004, 'M0002', 1, 9998);
INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0005, 'M0002', 2, 9997);
INSERT INTO mailbox (ID, mailboxid, connection, emailid) Values (0006, 'M0003', 1, 9996);


select m1.Id, m2.id
from Mailbox m1, Mailbox m2
Where m1.id <> m2.id
AND M1.mailboxid = m2.mailboxid
and m1.emailid = m2.emailid
and m1.connection <> m2.connection
and m1.id < m2.id
```

should give you this:

```
Id  id
1   2
```

You can trim the Mailbox id if necessary and add the null checks, if that is a problem as well.

Comment: Works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want something like that:

```sql
select a.ID, b.ID
from tableName a
join tableName b
on    a.ID > b.ID
and   a.MailboxID = b.MailboxID
and   a.EmailID = b.EmailID
and   a.Connection <> b.Connection
```

Another approach is to group by MailboxID and EmailID and show all IDs and Connections involved in each particular group.

Comment: I ended up using this approach for a similar problem as OP. It's probably more efficient that the `CROSS JOIN` in the accepted answer since the `CROSS JOIN` could get a little out of hand if there are a lot of rows in the table.